# neo4j dynamic programming query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, dynamic-programming, floyd-warshall

I would be really grateful if someone show me the way to calculate minimum path with a dynamic programming algorithm like Floyd and Warshall.The algorithm has to calculate the path at every interaction,it has to making decision about which nodes choose taking in consideration the nodes already traversed.

I have made a little explaination:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3i9KFQXzB89YXl0VkEzaDZDMHc/edit?usp=sharing

My graph is stored in a neo4j environment and it can increase in a serious way his dimension.  I use rest with everyman php neo4j libraries.
What is the best way to do this?
Traversal, cypher, gremilins, code a custom algorithm starting from http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-graph-algo/1.4/xref/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/shortestpath/FloydWarshall.html ?

Tnx in advance

Comment: Just fix the link to image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end my solution was to use traversal framework and build unmanaged extension.

M.